# How to .net standard 2.0 partial class grouping

Tags: c#, xamarin

I can not do partial class grouping for my problem in xamarin .net framework 2.0.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwMz1.png)

```
<ItemGroup>
<EmbeddedResource Update="Pages\Checkout Pages\Resource1.resx">
  <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
  <DependentUpon>CartPage.cs</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

I can set the Resx format file like this. But I can not put the file named CartPage.Design.cs under CartPage.cs.
How can I do it ?

Comment: If you select the files you want to Group together and then Right-click, do you see a `Group Items` option on the Context Menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generated in the .csproj file when `Access Modifier` is set to `Public` in the Resource1.resx view:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Update="Pages\CheckoutPages\Resource1.Designer.cs">
    <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    <DependentUpon>Resource1.resx</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Update="Pages\CheckoutPages\Resource1.resx">
    <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
    <LastGenOutput>Resource1.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

The `.Designer.cs` file is shown below the `.resx` file in the Solution Explorer.

The space characters in the folder name might be an issue.